# how can lexical scope work in c++ without closures?

Tags: c++, scope, closures

I'm confused by the topics of lexical scope and closures.

If i understand correctly, lexical scope means that function is evaluated with respect to the environment where it was defined. And closure is a pair of the environment and the function.

However, I have discovered that, for example, c++ didn't support closures in the past (It isn't exactly clear to me if it does support it currently, as I have found conflicting answers). If my understandings of these terms are correct, then doesn't the lexical scope require the existence of closures, as the function has to be executed in the environment where it was defined? if we didn't save this environment somewhere, wouldn't it be lost?

Comment: [Lambda Functions in C++11 - the Definitive Guide](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)

Comment: lambda functions didn't exist before c++11, so sadly it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: maybe you need to provide an example. to me its not clear what you don't understand about how calling functions in c++ works. the compiler resolves all symbols at compile time and if it can't then it doesn't compile.